# Which function is implicitly called in Python when setting a class variable via a class name?

Tags: python, python-3.4, setter, static-variables, class-variables

Let's say I've got a class with a 'private' class variable and an instance of the class. I want prevent setting the variable from outside of the class or execute a specific function when the class variable is being changed.

```
class SomeClass (object):
    __classVar = 5
    def getClassVar():
        return SomeClass.__classVar

instance = SomeClass()
```

The __classVar variable is not directly readable from outside of the class (e.g. I can't do 
     a = SomeClass.__ClassVar or b = instance.__classVar)
but the fact that the variable is private doesn't stop me from doing this:

```
SomeClass.__classVar = 6 
instance.__classVar = 10
```

even though this doesn't actually assign the value to the variable. E.g. the code below will still output 5.

```
class SomeClass (object):
        __classVar = 5
        def getClassVar():
            return SomeClass.__classVar

instance = SomeClass()
SomeClass.__classVar = 6
instance.__classVar = 10
print (getClassVar())  #outputs 5
```

I know that this statement

```
instance.__classVar = 10
```

is implicitly calling the  **__setattr__** function,  therefore I can overload it in the class definition.

```
class SomeClass (object):
    __classVar = 5
    def getClassVar():
            return SomeClass.__classVar

    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        print ("Setting a class variable via instance name")
        #do something specific
```

However, I don't know how to control what happens when attribute is set via the class name.

```
SomeClass.__var = 6   ##want to do something specific when this happens
```

Comment: Short answer: Don't do this. If people want to do stupid stuff, there's no preventing them, and weird workarounds will just make your code hard to work with.

Comment: Agree with Nick Johnson. There's no point to this and any halfway decent Python programmer knows that `__variable` is supposed to be private. You can't defend against nefariousness in any language.

Comment: Same technique, only instead of invoking `type(instance).__setattr__`, you invoking `type(SomeClass).__setattr__`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to follow [Nick Johnson's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100314/which-function-is-implicitly-called-in-python-when-setting-a-class-variable-via#comment52095131_32100314), howevre if you are in a situation where you extremely need that functionality, you might be interested in looking at Python metaclasses.

What you can do is create your own custom class inheriting from the `type` class, and overload `__setattr__` there:

```
class YourMeta(type):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # do your stuff here
```

And then simply make this the metaclass of your other class liek this:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = YourMeta

    # And so on
```

So now, you will have an overloaded `__setattr__` on the class level.

Comment: I thought this would be a way to go originally but it doesn't work for me. I expected the __metaclass__ attributte to change the type of SomeClass but it doesn't. 


`print (type(SomeClass)) #prints <class 'type'>` 

The overloaded __setattr__ function of YourMeta doesn't execute when I set a SomeClass's variable through the class name.

What could I be doing wrong?